# How to disable google indexing for material ui icons

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, googlebot

I have some problems with index of google.  I got search result  with Material-ui Icon text. How can I hide this text for googlebot?

```
<Icon className={style.pointerIcon}>
   fiber_manual_record
</Icon>
```

[image]

thanks in advance

Comment: have you added a meta description for the page?

Comment: @Anees , I have description, but google show page content with text from icons. I can't find  way to fix this

Comment: I  found that I can add tag  `data-nosnippet` for disable content.